# Request not sending request with correct ip

Tags: python, python-requests

I was testing out some proxies, but then I encountered an issue. When the origin IP was printed out, I realized it was mine and not the one from the proxy dictionary. I have tried most of the solution I found online, but none have helped.

How to reproduce:

```
URL = "https://httpbin.org/ip"
proxy_dict = {"http": "http://167.172.184.166:44258"}

r = requests.get(url=URL, proxies=proxy_dict)
print(r.text)
```

End result:

```
{
  "origin": "my ipv6"
}
```

Is there an issue with my code or proxy?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of a proxy, unless the proxy promises to hide your origin IP address. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server): *In computer networking, a proxy server is a server application or appliance that acts as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from servers that provide those resources. A proxy server thus functions on behalf of the client when requesting service, **potentially** masking the true origin of the request to the resource server.* (emphasis mine) - "potentially" does not mean a proxy must do so, and most don't.

Comment: @kaya3 Do you know which proxies hide your ip? Residential ones?

Comment: You will have to set a proxy for `https`.